# Unable To Instantiate StreamReader with HttpWebResponse Stream - System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, streamreader, httpwebresponse

I haven't posted here in a long time so please forgive me if I am not formatting this question properly. I am trying to login to a website(omitted) via the .NET objects HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse. Using Wireshark, I can see that my POST request is identical to Chrome's POST request when I login to this website through my application. I am having issues getting the full response back though.

`HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();`

This response object has all the appropriate response headers, but there is still data I would like to see that is being sent through HTTP chunked responses. I can verify this in Wireshark as well. My understanding is that I need to instantiate a StreamReader object to read this remaining data. My code is blowing up at this line:

`using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))`

The stack trace is showing this error:

> System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable.

How can I use this StreamReader object to read the entire response after my POST request is sent? Below is my code that sends the POST request for logging into the website. Please let me know if you have any questions and I will be happy to clarify any confusion.

```
public bool Login()
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://WEBSITE-REMOVED/CheckAccess");
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;

        //Set POST data.
        string postData = "institution=AAA";
        postData += "&ismobile=false";
        postData += "&id=BBB";
        postData += "&password=CCC";
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        //Configure HTTP POST request.
        request.Headers.Clear();
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Accept = @"text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*";
        request.Referer = @"http://WEBSITE-REMOVED/entry.html";
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US");
        request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";
        request.ContentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        request.Host = "op.responsive.net";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }//using

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            //TO-DO
        }
    }//try
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(ErrorLogDirectory + "Errors.txt", "Login() Exception\r\n" + System.DateTime.Now + "\r\n" + ex.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
    }//catch

    return false;
}//Login
```

Comment: The "stream is not readable" will result if there is an error return code, like 404, 503, 401, and so on. May be you need to check the response statuscode before reading the stream..

Comment: I agree there should be a status code check, but currently 200 OK is being returned by the web server every single time.

Comment: can u double check your code, that you are not trying to read the stream twice by mistake.

Comment: This is the code in its entirety right now. I declare and instantiate a CookieContainer member variable outside of this Login() method and that is it.

Comment: I see your code is clean and nothing suspicious. Can you pls set either request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false or request.KeepAlive = false and try again.

Comment: I added `request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;` just above the first using code block. This works! I'm able to instantiate the StreamReader and call StreamReader.ReadToEnd() without any issues. I've kept the KeepAlive property set to true as well. I don't see any change in the wireshark traces. Can you explain to me what this is doing? I am basically saying no additional verification data is going to be sent after this initial POST request right?

Comment: For some reason client is receiving back the 100-continue response AND the 200 OK response in a single call from the server, all before the client has even written the body of the POST request. This is strange behavior of server. Setting Expect100Continue to false just a workaround. Glad it worked for you.